# how to get data from web service using xml

Tags: javascript

i am try to get data from web service ,, the web service is

http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx?op=GetCountries

i am use the suds.js

how to get the data from the web service or how to call web service without send parameters or please help me in anything

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post your code (or explain what you've done so far) and describe how it's not working correctly.

Comment: i need to put picker in iphone app have the countries to let the user sign up and chose the country from the picker ,, i found some web service provide the list of countries.

Comment: i used suds.js function to call web service my code is work good but when i call the countries web service its not work,, i htink there is some problem with the parametrs coz when i call the web service with parameters its work,, but when i call it without parameters its not work,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx?op=GetCountries",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function (xmldata, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {

       //Do your thing! For instance:
       console.log(xmldata);

    }
 });
```